# Commands causing slow down

Tags: wpf, performance, command

First off, I'm fully aware of how contrived this example is, and it's lack of virtualization, but I'm using it to demonstrate a problem I've been experiencing in a more complicated system that would be very difficult to show. And this seems like a simple way to demonstrate it.

The following code creates a menu and an ItemsControl bound to a large list of strings(I'm using 10,000), each being viewed as a button.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="Test">
            <MenuItem Header="A" />
            <MenuItem Header="B" />
            <MenuItem Header="C" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LotsOfStrings}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Open" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Expander>
</DockPanel>
```

As expected, this is slow to load, but once it has loaded, the 'Test' menu is responsive (that is, there is no noticeable lag as you mouse over the menu items).

Now make the following small change of adding a command to the button.

```
<Button Content="Open" Command="Open"/>
```

Now the Menu becomes horribly laggy. For some reason, mousing over different menu items calls `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` which gets executed for each button, causing the slow down.

So I'm wondering if there is anyway of disabling the Commanding updates on controls that aren't visible? so in this example, if the expander is collapsed, can I some how stop the buttons from still handling the commanding updates?

Comment: Could you post the code of your `Command` as it's relative to your question, thanks.

Comment: This was using a command that didn't actually do anything, the Can Execute was always true and the execute didn't do anything. But that doesn't appear to be the problem, the problem (I believe) is the commanding infrastructure that is doing lots of work behind the scenes